# Quarkus and DynamoDBMapper - Failing to build a native executable - Error Random/SplittableRandom

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, quarkus, graalvm-native-image, dynamodb-mapper

I've got a Quarkus project where DynamoDBMapper is also being used. Everything runs perfectly in dev mode.

But when running this command `mvn package -Pnative -pl my-module -DskipTests` it gives me this error

```
[my-module-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:61]      [total]: Error: Unsupported features in 2 methods
Detailed message:
Error: Detected an instance of Random/SplittableRandom class in the image heap. Instances created during image generation have cached seed values and don't behave as expected.  To see how this object got instantiated use --trace-object-instantiation=java.util.Random. The object was probably created by a class initializer and is reachable from a static field. You can request class initialization at image runtime by using the option --initialize-at-run-time=<class-name>. Or you can write your own initialization methods and call them explicitly from your main entry point.
Trace: Object was reached by 
    reading field com.amazonaws.retry.PredefinedBackoffStrategies$EqualJitterBackoffStrategy.random of
        constant com.amazonaws.retry.PredefinedBackoffStrategies$EqualJitterBackoffStrategy@2ad70ff4 reached by 
    reading field com.amazonaws.retry.PredefinedBackoffStrategies$SDKDefaultBackoffStrategy.equalJitterBackoffStrategy of
        constant com.amazonaws.retry.PredefinedBackoffStrategies$SDKDefaultBackoffStrategy@64d81db reached by 
    reading field com.amazonaws.retry.RetryPolicy.backoffStrategy of
        constant com.amazonaws.retry.RetryPolicy@7ce3fed7 reached by 
    scanning method com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientConfigurationFactory.getDefaultConfig(AmazonDynamoDBClientConfigurationFactory.java:31)
Call path from entry point to com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientConfigurationFactory.getDefaultConfig(): 
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientConfigurationFactory.getDefaultConfig(AmazonDynamoDBClientConfigurationFactory.java:31)
    at com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory.getConfig(ClientConfigurationFactory.java:36)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.resolveClientConfiguration(AwsClientBuilder.java:169)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.access$000(AwsClientBuilder.java:54)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder$SyncBuilderParams.<init>(AwsClientBuilder.java:505)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.getSyncClientParams(AwsClientBuilder.java:441)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
    at integration.common.config.DynamoDBConfig.dynamoDBMapper(DynamoDBConfig.java:23)
    at integration.common.config.DynamoDBConfig_ProducerMethod_dynamoDBMapper_f166ddedc44150bc6c5ef50fafe7a64b599d849a_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at integration.common.config.DynamoDBConfig_ProducerMethod_dynamoDBMapper_f166ddedc44150bc6c5ef50fafe7a64b599d849a_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:111)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:35)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:32)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.SystemPropertiesSupport.initializeLazyValue(SystemPropertiesSupport.java:216)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.SystemPropertiesSupport.getProperty(SystemPropertiesSupport.java:169)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.Target_java_lang_System.getProperty(JavaLangSubstitutions.java:287)
    at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_ARRAY_System_getProperty_deeeaa72a006d330408a3b7d002c7533e108bc28(generated:0)
```

The dependency for DynamoDBMapper in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.205</version>
    </dependency>
```

The configuration class

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DynamoDBConfig {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "DYNAMO_DB_TABLE_NAME")
    String tableName;

    @Produces
    public DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper() {

        return new DynamoDBMapper(
                AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build(),
                tableNameConfig()
        );
    }

    private DynamoDBMapperConfig tableNameConfig() {

        return new DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder()
                       .withTableNameOverride(TableNameOverride.withTableNameReplacement(
                tableName)).build();
    }
}
```

I've found out that this `AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build()` specific line is causing this issue.

I've tried adding `com.amazonaws` to application.properties to solve this issue. Which it does locally with the previous command but fails in a aws lambda when it runs.

```
quarkus.native.additional-build-args=--initialize-at-run-time=org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMEngineImpl\
    \\,io.netty.util.internal.logging.Log4JLogger\
    \\,com.amazonaws
```

Comment: How did you use DynamoDBMapper? https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-amazon-services/dev/amazon-dynamodb.html does not support DynamoDBMapper.